# Flutter mocking a ChangeNotifierProvider and setting provider values

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito, widget, widget-test-flutter

Ok, bear with me as I am just beginning to learn widget testing. I have a MainAppBar widget that has an AuthProvider above it in the widget tree, which is necessary to do an auth check and subsequent logout if a user is in fact authenticated. This is a silly scenario, but being able to test it will be useful for many other scenarios in my app.

```
IconButton(
 icon: Icon(Icons.logout), 
 onPressed: () {
   if (Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).isAuthenticated) {
     Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).signOut();
     Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
   }
 }
)
```

I am mocking the AuthProvider like so

```
class MockAuthProvider extends Mock implements AuthProvider {}
```

with mockito and wrapping the widget like so

```
MockAuthProvider mockAuthProvider = MockAuthProvider();
  
Widget makeTestableWidget({Widget child}) => MaterialApp(
  home: ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
    create: (_) => mockAuthProvider,
    child: Scaffold(
      body: child,
    ),
  ),
);
```

The `isAuthenticated` bool is based on a simple enum status check, so as long as I set the status, I can test for true and false scenarios, etc. In my test I would like to set a status and test whether `signOut` and `Navigator` are called or not.

```
testWidgets('Clicking on logout icon...', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  mockAuthProvider.setAuthProviderStatus(AuthProviderStatus.Unauthenticated);
  print(mockAuthProvider.isAuthenticated);
  await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(child: MainAppBar(title: 'test')));
    
  var icon = find.byIcon(Icons.logout);
  await tester.tap(icon);
  await tester.pump();

  verifyNever(mockAuthProvider.signOut());
});
```

The `setAuthProviderStatus` setter sets the status and the `isAuthenticated` does a basic check:

```
bool get isAuthenticated {
  if (status == AuthProviderStatus.Authenticated) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

The AuthProvider initializes the status as a default of `Uninitialized`, so though this check could be expanded to consider null, it should be fine for now. In my MainAppBar widget, the `isAuthenticated` bool is coming back as null and throwing the exception `Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null` since the if statement requires a bool and null causes it to fail. The print in my test `print(mockAuthProvider.isAuthenticated);` is also null. I've successfully tested with passing the actual AuthProvider and am not having the same issue, though that clearly will not work for testing purposes.

How can I set values in a mock Provider so that the widgets that are under them are are aware of them?

Answer (score 3):

In case someone stumbles on this... To achieve this, you can stub any provider functionality as needed:

Instead of:

```
mockAuthProvider.setAuthProviderStatus(AuthProviderStatus.Unauthenticated);
```

you can use mockito like so:

```
when(mockAuthProvider.isAuthenticated)
  .thenReturn(<VALUE YOU WANT TO TEST>);
```

so when the line `Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).isAuthenticated` is executed, isAuthenticated will have a stubbed value.

Here are the tests I ended up writing for that Icon's onPressed functionality:

```
void setIsAuthenticated(bool isAuthenticated) {
  when(mockAuthProvider.isAuthenticated)
    .thenReturn(isAuthenticated);
  when(mockAuthProvider.hasListeners).thenReturn(false);
}

testWidgets('Clicking on logout icon does not call signOut if user is not authenticated', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  setIsAuthenticated(false);

  await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(child: MainAppBar(title: 'Test')));

  var icon = find.byIcon(Icons.logout);
  await tester.tap(icon);
  await tester.pump();

  verifyNever(mockAuthProvider.signOut());
});

testWidgets('Clicking on logout icon calls signOut if user is '
  'authenticated AND push replace route', 
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
      
  setIsAuthenticated(true);

  await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(child: MainAppBar(title: 'Test')));

  var icon = find.byIcon(Icons.logout);
  await tester.tap(icon);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  verify(mockAuthProvider.signOut());
  verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any));
  expect(find.text('Login'), findsOneWidget);
});
```